# Issues with Network Level Authentication after migrating DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, migration, windows-server-2016

**Notice NLA is enabled**

Since Windows Server 2016 came out I've migrated my 2012R2 server to a new instance of 2016.

I've migrated the

1. AD
2. DNS
3. DHCP
4. CS

to the new server.

I have validated every piece in the lab, and everything seems to be working smoothly EXCEPT:

**I cannot RDP to my server w/ NLA enabled using a domain account.**

I get the error that I cannot connect to the server with NLA (see screenshot):

[image: NLA issues]

It **does** work if I:

- Connect to the machine remotely with a local account
- Inside the
  remote machine RDP to itself, and then using the domain account to
  log in
- Taking over that session from OUTSIDE

Any clues here on why this might occur?

Comment: `Unfortunately this does not work ANYMORE` - It would help if you actually told us some details about the nature of the problem. Saying that it doesn't work anymore doesn't tell us anything about the nature of the problem. Telling us about your workaround also doesn't help us to understand the actual problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty right, pasted wrong version!

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. What happens when you try to connect? Do you get any error messages? Is there any useful information in the event logs?

Comment: @joeqwerty picture this time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough resetting the machine password did not work.

What did work is leaving and rejoining the domain...

Sadly I don't have more time to investigate.